# Replace placeholder with same named php-variable

Tags: php, str-replace

```
$name = "MasterOfDisaster";
$age  = "666";

$string = "My name is [name] and i'm [age] years old";
```

Now I' would like to replace all values between two characters and change them to a same named php variable

```
[foo] > $foo
I want to get this without replacing with arrays:
$string = "My name is $name and i'm $age years old";
```

Can I achieve this with ereg_replace? I'don't want to use str_replace() in combination with arrays to catch all my values in the text.

My preg_replace() so far:

```
$placeholder = preg_replace("/\[(.*?)]/", ${"$1"}, $string);
echo $placeholder;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$array = array('name' => "MasterOfDisaster", 'age' => "666");
$string = "My name is [name] and i'm [age] years old";
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $string = preg_replace('/\['.$key.'\]/i', $value, $string);
}
echo $string;
```

Output is:

```
My name is MasterOfDisaster and i'm 666 years old
```

NOTE: Do not use `ereg_replace` functions because it is deprecated. Yous `preg_replace` functions instead.

Comment: Hey, thank's for the deprecated info but i would like to replace it without using arrays if possible.

Comment: You need to know, what do you want to replace with what.

Comment: I want to replace with the same name between two characters: `[foo] to $foo`